# DataTable add other column in table

Tags: c#, datatable

I created this table and the result is as follows.

[image]

The code I used to create this table is as follows.
and it works for me correctly

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Table1");

dt1.Columns.Add("Num", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("product1a", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("product1b", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("total1", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("product2a", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("product2b", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("product2c", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("total2", typeof(Int32));

object[] o1 = { 1, "10/10/2017", "name 1", 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3 };
object[] o2 = { 2, "20/10/2017", "name 2", 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5 };
object[] o3 = { 3, "15/08/2017", "name 3", 1, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4 };

dt1.Rows.Add(o1);
dt1.Rows.Add(o2);
dt1.Rows.Add(o3);            

var grid = new GridView();
grid.DataSource = dt1;
grid.DataBind();

Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExportFetsVinculats.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

grid.RenderControl(htw);

Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
return Content("");
```

up to here everything is correct, but you would have to implement the table of the following way.

[image]

Is it possible to add two more columns that act as headers?

Comment: I had to do this a few years back in a webforms application, look into the rowcreated event for your gridview, then check if it is a header that is being created, you can then create and attach a table cell, and change its columnspan property to the number of columns you wish to merge. I no linger have the code at hand though sorry.. the second accepted answer here should help you. https://forums.asp.net/t/1910325.aspx?Heading+and+subheading+in+gridview

Comment: Thanks for the help, the link that you have given me has been very helpful.
My previous statements had been wrong.
I attach the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the code with the simple solution:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Table1");

dt1.Columns.Add("Num", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("product1a", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("product1b", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("total1", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("product2a", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("product2b", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("product2c", typeof(Int32));
dt1.Columns.Add("total2", typeof(Int32));

object[] o1 = { 1, "10/10/2017", "name 1", 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3 };
object[] o2 = { 2, "20/10/2017", "name 2", 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5 };
object[] o3 = { 3, "15/08/2017", "name 3", 1, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4 };
        
dt1.Rows.Add(o1);
dt1.Rows.Add(o2);
dt1.Rows.Add(o3);

GridView grid = new GridView();                    

grid.DataSource = dt1;
grid.DataBind();

GridView HeaderGrid = grid;
GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
HeaderCell.Text = "";
HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

HeaderCell = new TableCell();
HeaderCell.Text = "Head Products 1";
HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 3;
HeaderCell.Font.Bold = true;
HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

HeaderCell = new TableCell();
HeaderCell.Text = "Head Products 2";
HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
HeaderCell.Font.Bold = true;
HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
        
HeaderGrid.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExportFetsVinculats.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

grid.RenderControl(htw);

Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
return Content("");
```

Or:

```
public ActionResult retorna_excel()
{
     DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Table1");

     dt1.Columns.Add("Num", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));
     dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
     dt1.Columns.Add("product1a", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("product1b", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("total1", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("product2a", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("product2b", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("product2c", typeof(Int32));
     dt1.Columns.Add("total2", typeof(Int32));

     object[] o1 = { 1, "10/10/2017", "name 1", 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3 };
     object[] o2 = { 2, "20/10/2017", "name 2", 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5 };
     object[] o3 = { 3, "15/08/2017", "name 3", 1, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4 };
        
     dt1.Rows.Add(o1);
     dt1.Rows.Add(o2);
     dt1.Rows.Add(o3);

     GridView grid = new GridView();                    

     grid.DataSource = dt1;
     grid.DataBind();

     List<Tuple<string, int, bool, HorizontalAlign>> list_header = new List<Tuple<string, int, bool, HorizontalAlign>>();
     list_header.Add(new Tuple<string, int, bool, HorizontalAlign>("", 3, false, HorizontalAlign.Center));
     list_header.Add(new Tuple<string, int, bool, HorizontalAlign>("Head Products 1", 3, true, HorizontalAlign.Center));
     list_header.Add(new Tuple<string, int, bool, HorizontalAlign>("Head Products 2", 4, true, HorizontalAlign.Center));            

     get_header_table(grid, list_header);

     Response.ClearContent();
     Response.Buffer = true;
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExportFetsVinculats.xls");
     Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

     Response.Charset = "";
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

     grid.RenderControl(htw);

     Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
     return Content("");
}

private void get_header_table(GridView grid, List<Tuple<string, int, bool, HorizontalAlign>> list_header)
{
    GridView HeaderGrid = grid;
    GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

    TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();

    foreach (Tuple<string, int, bool, HorizontalAlign> item in list_header)
    {
        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = item.Item1;
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = item.Item2;
        HeaderCell.Font.Bold = item.Item3;
        HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = item.Item4;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
    }

    HeaderGrid.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);
}
```